# how Automatically go from first.php to second.php

Tags: php

I need that when user open first.php, Automatically go from first.php to second.php without click on link or bottom.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use header function.

```
header('location:second.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

> header("Location: link/to/second.php");

This will redirect the user whithout inteaction.